# SQL Group By, Get The row of the Min function

Tags: sql, group-by

I know you cant Group By one column in a table (Although I wish it was that easy) but can I at last grab the fields of the row selected by the min?

```
prd_id prd_description Stock Todays Order Tomorrows Order Next Batch prd_status Prd_line prd_estimate_time left_to_produce
     7 Product A          14           14             234      16249 New               2 17May16 17:54:02            16249
     9 Product B         754            0               0       2128 New               5 17May16 18:11:28             2128
    11 Product C           0          157            5106       6850 New               2 17May16 18:40:04             6850
    17 Product D        1248         4296            9120       4728 New               8 18May16 04:50:09             9456
    17 Product D        1248         4296            9120       4728 New              10 18May16 16:55:09             9456
```

Now for Product D all is the same except its produced on two lines and different times of the day.

I want one product per line with the lowest Estimated time displayed and the line its produced on

such as

```
prd_id prd_description Stock Todays Order Tomorrows Order Next Batch prd_status Prd_line prd_estimate_time left_to_produce
     7 Product A          14           14             234      16249 New               2 17May16 17:54:02            16249
     9 Product B         754            0               0       2128 New               5 17May16 18:11:28             2128
    11 Product C           0          157            5106       6850 New               2 17May16 18:40:04             6850
    17 Product D        1248         4296            9120       4728 New               8 18May16 04:50:09             9456
```

Comment: Your question is about SQL and Grouping but you have posted none of you SQL code.

Comment: Evidently by the answer below I didn't need to.

Comment: Thanks for the Table Edit @Strawberry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presuming sql-server (>= 2005) as rdbms you can use the ranking function `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT t.*, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY prd_id  -- add more columns if you want to group by multiple columns 
                                       ORDER BY prd_estimate_time ASC)
   FROM dbo.TableName
)
SELECT prd_id, prd_description, Stock, [Todays Order], [Tomorrows Order], [Next Batch], prd_status, Prd_line, prd_estimate_time, left_to_produce
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: Cant believe I forgot about that, wood for the trees in this case. Thanks